# How appropriate is it to ask for upvotes in chat?

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette

I recently saw in PHP chat room that one user [asked for upvotes](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6858872#6858872).

> [image]

Now I'm wondering these things:

1. Is it appropriate to ask for upvotes in chat?
2. Should we ask for upvotes for either badges/hats or anything like that?
3. Is this behavior we expect from high rep users?
4. Can we ask for upvotes after reaching the rep cap?

Comment: How terrible. The hat should be revoked. This is high up there in the list of crimes against humanity.

Comment: Wait, where did he mention hats?

Comment: @animuson I see what you did there.

Comment: one thing .... its up to other ,,,, neal wont shoot anyone who does not upvote its like review pls ..... and attract more people to see answer ..and it isnt crime .. if they found it worthy to upvote they can its up to them ..if they found wrong they can down vote too....

Comment: Hang him high! (And then give me Clint Eastwood's hat.)

Comment: @JoshCaswell capital punishment is not a good idea ...its not according to human right ...lol

Comment: Well, I suppose we could tie the rope around his torso and let him down when he has learned his lesson, @NullPointer. I don't see the hat angle for me in that, though.

Comment: What a ridiculous question.

Comment: We can't go hunting people here for every little thing they say in chat, often meant as a joke. Really.

Comment: If SO isn't going to remind folks to accept and/or upvote then someone has to.  Heck yes it's acceptable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is surrounding the [Winter Bash promotion](http://winterba.sh/), as you mentioned. If we want to continue to have nice things like hats at the end of the year, I would hope that all involved would try to keep noise down to a minimum, so other users don't find the promotion to be a source of annoyance (even if not opted-in) and object to Stack Overflow's participation in future events.

It is fine to ask other users in chat to evaluate content that you, or any other user contributes. In fact, that's one of the things chat was *designed* to facilitate. That's why questions and answers posted in most rooms are displayed in a special way. Directly asking for up-votes can and *will* be seen as noise by some (if not most) users, I'd suggest not doing it, especially in *multiple* rooms. In this case, you have to remember that you're chatting with people that might (gasp) conceivably *hate* hats!

Still, *context* is really important when considering things that transpired in chat. I can't really say 'yes' or 'no' to your question points, they all depend on the context of the conversation. Is the user just being sarcastic? Is the request simply rhetorical? If you feel something is amiss, use the flag system in chat to let a moderator know.

Comment: How about hiding questions tagged with WinterBash from those who have opted out of hats ?

Comment: One does not simply opt out of hats.

Comment: I HATE HATS! @Bart

Comment: @PeeHaa Consider yourself flagged as "offensive"...for shame, for shame

Answer (score 12):

The habit of sharing posts is something not only built into the system, but encouraged further by badges for giving out special kinds of links. We do want people to increase the visibility of their posts, because that increases the visibility to those who actually need the valuable information contained in those posts.

The only questionable part here is the framing. Which, not unlike asking for spare change from a passerby on the street, is simply asking for those within range to not just look at the question, but vote for it as well. This particular case might be in the context of an event, but we can even divorce the event from the situation since the hat in question is derived from the same requirements as a badge. It's just as realistic outside of the context of this event as it would be if it happened at any other time in the year, and the framing's effect will be the same.

This kind of behavior is thus identical to pestering people in comments to accept your own answer, or to upvote while accepting, or any other large number of behaviors all related to asking for votes. In fact, it's really just the same as posting a link to a post for sharing, and then commenting "Please upvote me!". Just as one might flag such noisy commentary for removal, the same can be said for this situation - community agreement that the comment is undesirable is required for the flag to take effect. That the sharing link is conjoined to the commentary, well, that is a consequence a user should've considered initially.

Answer (score 10):

> 1. is this appropriate to ask for upvote in chat ?
> 2. should we ask for upvote for either badge /hat or anything like that ?
> 3. is this behavior we suppose from high rep user ?
> 4. can we ask for upvote after reaching rep cap ?

### No!

Comment: **1.** Why not? An upvote shows that people agree with the answer and that it is correct. **2.** I never asked for a hat.

Comment: **1.** We can't (should not) ask anyone for upvote anywhere. **2.** same comment.

Comment: **1.** Why not? Where does it say that anywhere? **2.** same comment. I am out for today. Happy Holidays!

Comment: @hims056: You obviously haven't spent enough time in the Tavern...

Comment: @animuson Enough time? I do not use chat. But I feel asking for voting our post is not a good idea.

Comment: Why? All you've said is you don't support it, but you've provided absolutely no evidence to back it up. What harm does it do to the community? Like I said in my answer, people don't just upvote things because you ask them to do so. No one is going to go upvote some crappy post just because. People post links to random questions and answers in the Tavern *all the time*.

Comment: You've got to admit that this is a pretty lousy answer, whether one would agree with that bottom line or not. I'm sure you have some underlying motivations for it, so why not share those with us.

Comment: I've asked for upvotes for the answer of another user (not in chat), because It was an old question, and the new answer was more valuable than the one that had the most votes.

Comment: Yeah gotta say I agree with @Bart here. This answer would hold more water if you actually elaborated on how (in poor taste, unfair to other answers, answers should stand on their own merits etc) it is a bad idea to ask for upvotes instead of just theatrically exclaiming **"No!"**.

Comment: @animuson Evidence doesn't need to be hard-set or anything. I answered No because it's my strong beliefs that it isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Bart It's a simple answer that it is not appropriate to do ... which I believe. So I directly answered OP's question. Not every answer need description.

Comment: @Asad I don't think this answer need to be elaborated. I answered because I believe it's not a good idea. That's all. And all upvoters also believes the same. That's why none of them replied here.

Answer (score 9):

Why not? How is this any different than advertising a question or answer to your friends? You may not specifically ask them "hey can you upvote this for me?" but by showing it to them, you are sure hoping that they will. It's kind of like "hey check out this answer I posted that I know you have the privilege to upvote *wink wink*."

It may be a more sneaky way of going about getting upvotes, but a) there's nothing you can do about it, b) it doesn't really harm anything as most people will not just blindly throw out an upvote without still agreeing with the content, and c) there's nothing you can do about it.

There is no rule, anywhere, that says you *can't* directly ask people for upvotes, only that a user can't mass upvote another user. Most people just go about it in a more indirect way. If he had just posted the link to the question and said "hey, check this out" he would probably have gotten the same number of upvotes.

Comment: `+1` I am out of votes for today, but will up this tomorrow ^_^

Comment: A note: too much of this makes it vote ringing, which is a bannable offence. So while there is no rule against a few such messages, too many such messages are Not Good

Comment: Very true, although vote ringing is usually organized. This is not.

Comment: Well, my stance on this is almost the same as this answer. The only difference is that I think the problem is that *explicitly asking* for upvotes (or downvotes), on an SO property should be not allowed. Posting the answer/question for visibility in chat is fine. It's fine to say "Please review this". But once you say "Downvote" or "Upvote", it's a bit too much, and is gaming the system...

Answer (score -1):

I am the offender (apparently).

I see no issue in asking people to upvote a question or answer if it is a good contribution to Stack Overflow.

Nowhere did I mention hats in my chat message there, but yes, hats were in mind.

But I was **not** forcing anybody to vote! I was asking for votes,  I assumed people could make their own decisions when it cam to placing their votes.